# How to get record created today by rails activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, rails-activerecord

How should I write the conditional statement for when I want to get all the records which were created today?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

```
Post.where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```

PS: This answer has been modified as answer by Harish Shetty was better than mine. As my answer is accepted one. I have updated this answer for community support

Comment: In the latest versions this can be even more streamlined with `Post.where(created_at: Time.current.all_day)`

Answer (score 130):

I know this question has an accepted answer. The solution suggested in the accepted answer can cause performance issues when the table size grows.

Typically, if you perform lookups based on `created_at` column, add an index on the table in your migration file.

```
add_index :posts, :created_at
```

Now, to lookup records created today:

**Rails 3/4**

```
Post.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

To lookup posts created on a specific day.

```
Post.where(:created_at => (date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day))
```

---------     *OR*    -------------

Add a static method to your model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.today
    where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
  end
end

Post.today #returns posts today
```

**Rails 2**

```
Post.all(:conditions => ["created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day])
```

---------     *OR*    -------------

Add a named_scope to your model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
  named_scope :today, lambda { 
    {
      :conditions => ["created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day]
    }
  }
end

Post.today #returns posts today
```

Comment: Great point about indexing. Just wanted to clarify that the `scope` example in this post is for Rails 3 only, since it looks like it's under the Rails 2 heading. In Rails 2, you would need to use `named_scope` rather than `scope`.

Also, in Rails 3, you could equivalently use a class method

`def self.today
  where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day)
end`

which is probably cleaner than using a scope in this case, since it allows you to forgo the lambda.

Comment: @evanrmurphy can/should you revise your comment from "Rails 3 only" to "Rails 3 and greater"?

Comment: @kaichanvong I'm not familiar with Rails 4, so I would like to say "Rails 3 (and greater?)" but SO won't let me edit the comment :-/

Answer (score 35):

Rails 5.1 has an `all_day` helper that's useful here.

```
Post.where(created_at: Date.today.all_day)
```

or

```
Post.where(created_at: Date.parse("YYYY-MM-DD").all_day)
```

Answer (score 31):

MySQL:

```
Model.all :condition => ["DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today] # rails 2
Model.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today) # rails 3
```

PostgreSQL:

```
Model.all :condition => ["created_at::date = ?", Date.today] # rails 2
Model.where("created_at::date = ?", Date.today) # rails 3
```

Answer (score 20):

Mohit Jain's answer adapted for Rails3

```
Model.where "DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", Time.now
```

Answer (score 9):

`Post.where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)`

This "namescopes" the attribute with the `table_name`.

Answer (score 5):

model.rb

```
scope :posted_today, -> { posted_between_period(Time.now.midnight, Time.now.end_of_day) }
```

posts_controller.rb

```
Post.posted_today
```

Comment: @Pathiv, `between_period` looks interesting. I didn't find any documentation for it. Can you provide some link? How does rails choose the column for comparison?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, none of the other solutions in this post nor others on StackOverflow worked for me (using Rails 4.2.4 and Ruby 2.2.3p173). This is the only query that I could get to work with my Postgres database:

```
Post.where("created_at >= TIMESTAMP 'now'")
```

Answer (score -1):

To query records which created from today

**Use scope with arel**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
  scope :create_from_today, -> {
    where(arel_table[:created_at].gteq(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day))
  }
end
```

Then we can use it

```
today_posts = Post.created_from_today
```

Comment: `where('created_at >= now()')` would only find items where the created_at was in the future.

Comment: Yeah I would remove it from the answer, nice catch thanks

Comment: The issue you now have is that records that are marked with future dates would be presented as well as those for today. If you're trying to avoid using between, you should specify `.lteq(Time.zone.now.end_of_day))` as well.

Answer (score -5):

In rails 4.2.3 for getting the records created today, using mysql use the following.

**@usergoals = Goal.where("userid = :userid and Date(created_at) = :date", { userid: params[:id], date: Date.today })**

here i am using multiple conditions if you want you can edit it for single condition.