# Ruby date comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

`@student = Student.find(:all, :conditions => {:school_id => school.id,:created_at => Date.today })`
I need to write this ruby query to retrieve all students in a school which students date of creation should be the same day.
But This giving nil values.When I use "if" condition, I can use `if created_at.to_date == Date.today.to_date`.
So my question is how I can convert the datetime formatted symbol(:created_at) to date format.
(means, Here Student.find(.., :created_at.to_date => Date.today.to_date)  is not possible,What is the alternate way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the trick is that `created_at` is a time value, not a date value. One way of solving this problem, recommended by [this StackOverflow answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919720/how-to-get-record-created-today-by-rails-activerecord/2919741#2919741), is to convert the `created_at` value to a date during the query:

```
school.students.all(:conditions => ["DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", Time.now])
```

(Note that I refactored the query to use the school's `has_many :students` relationship.)