# Time.now.beginning_of_year does not start at the beginning of the year

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, date, activerecord

Trying to get records that were created this year, I stumbled upon [this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919720/how-to-get-record-created-today-by-rails-activerecord). The second answer says you get all records from a model that were created today by saying:

```
Model.where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day)
```

So, naturally, I tried the same thing with `Time.now.beginning_of_year`, and it works just fine.

However, what struck me as interesting is that the outputted query (I tried it in the console) is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `invoices` WHERE (created_at >= '2012-12-31 23:00:00')
```

I wasn't aware that 2013 already began at 2012-12-31 23:00:00? How's that?

Comment: Are you in a time zone which is UTC+1, by any chance? If so, I suspect `Time.now.beginning_of_year` is giving you the *local* "beginning of year", and ActiveRecord is converting that into UTC. Only a guess though - I don't know Ruby at all...

Comment: Could be... But how would ActiveRecord do that if I am only running it locally?

Comment: Well I expect `Time.now` knows what time zone it's in, and ActiveRecord is just converting that to UTC. That's easy.

Comment: How does `Time.now` know? BTW, I am in UTC +1 ;-) So that might in fact be the problem.

Comment: @Charles are you setting the timezone in `config/application.rb` file (look for the line beginning with `config.time_zone`)? As a rule, it's usually a better idea to set a timezone in Rails and then use `Time.zone.now`

Comment: @theIV You should write this as answer, this worked :) Thanks!

Comment: Done and done. Glad you got it working @Charles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't set it yet, you should set your timezone in the `config/application.rb` file. Look for the line that begins with `config.time_zone`. (If you aren't sure what value to give, you can run `rake time:zones:all` to get a list of all available timezones.)

Once you've set your timezone, you should use `Time.zone.now`, as opposed to `Time.now`. This will properly "scope" your times to your timezone.

Check [the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) for more details on `TimeWithZone`.